# How do I disable automatic class creation in OrientDB?

Tags: java, graph, nosql, database, orientdb

How do I disable automatic class creation in OrientDB? I mean, suppose I create an edge like this:

```
sourceVertex.addEdge("PointsTo", targetVertex);
```

OrientDB will create a class `PointsTo` if it not already exists. Is it possible to configure OrientDB to throw an exception when a non-existent class is given?

Answer (score 1):

Execute this SQL command against OrientDB database:

```
alter database custom useClassForEdgeLabel=false
```

For more information look at [OrientDB Documentation](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop).

Comment: Thanks. This way it will create a field "label" instead of a class. I would prefer an exception, because I'm creating my classes (schema) manually. So my users should never pass a non-existent class as parameter.